# How do I execute the code and see the results using twitter util-eval

Tags: scala, twitter-util

I am trying to compile and execute a "hello world" program using twitter util-eval library. But not able to get results printed.

My intention is not just to compile and execute hello world example, large scala files with dependencies should compile and run.

```
import com.twitter.util.Eval
object ScalaCompiler3 {
     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
         val eval = new Eval()
         val fileContents = "class Test {\n\n println (\"Hello World!\")\n\n}"
         val compile = eval.apply[Unit](fileContents)
         println(compile)
     }
}
```

How do I execute the code and see the results? am not able to get proper API documentation for util-eval. Using util-eval_2.11-6.43.0.jar taken from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/util-eval_2.11)

Comment: Your code creates a class whose constructor prints hello world, but you're not instantiating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As erip mentioned in the comments, the source string you're compiling makes a class, Test, but since you never instantiate the class it never runs the code within.

If you replace:

```
val fileContents = "class Test {\n\n println (\"Hello World!\")\n\n}"
```

with:

```
val fileContents = "println(\"Hello World!\")\n\n}"
```

That will execute the code you're looking to execute. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: It is not as such printing "Hello World" it is compiling properly.  Do i need to add anything else to invoke this code?

Comment: Having not worked with your framework I'm not certain; can you try setting `fileContents` to simply `"println(\"Hello World!\")"`?

Comment: It prints Hello World. if I use just `"println(\"Hello World!\")"`. Now I have to see about working with objects. Thanks for your time.